# Are there special key events in Windows I can't handle?

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard

Are there any key events I cannot handle in my C# program?
For example, can I implement differently Windows's events: Ctrl+Alt+Del, Alt+Tab, WindowsKey+D, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that in any case there is absolutely no way to bypass the automatic handling of a Ctrl+Alt+Del in Windows. So even when you can handle this as an event in your program, the user will still get an additional task manager / login manager.

Comment: Is that true for the other Windows events, or just for Ctrl+Alt+Del?

Comment: Classic example is using VNC or RDP - using Ctrl+Alt+Del will always result in your local machine receiving the command.

Answer (score 0):

every keystroke results in a windowsmessage and every key has a keycode (except the special function keys of some keybords like the gamer keyboards used to have).

overwrite wndproc and get those messages to fire your events.